# Run phonegap / Cordova with easy way

Tags: cordova

Because I am totally confused on how to run `phonegap` efficient and easy through and IDE please could anyone tell me on how to run it using ripple and android emulator for tasting?

I show it can run through `eclipse, aptana, sencha touch` etc but how can I understand it?

You will really help me if someone could answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you start something new first hit the documentation

[cordova documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/)

There are lot of examples and all details available. Yes cordova can be used in different ways. You can start with **command line interface (CLI)**

[CLI details](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface)

There is complete description how you can set and run cordova. You will need some stuff to download like node.js, ANT etc. it's described there. If you successfully install all setup then you can simply run with command

```
cordova run android
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the links. I try to find an IDE to run it and I am totally disappointed.